# Spring oauth2 inserts hash sign instead of ? upon redirect to resource server with token

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have my Spring Boot application working with one exception.
for implicit grant type after user approves access and redirected to resource server the authorization fails due to the hash sign instead of ?
http://localhost:8080/testapp/test#access_token=621c8fce-4fe0-4893-9d96-63a7da8258ce&token_type=bearer&expires_in=26934&scope=trust%20read%20write

If manually corrected "#" to "?" the resource server validates the access token and provides services.
I am using latest and greatest spring-security-oauth2 2.0.6.RELEASE
Can somebody recommend the way how to override this?

Answer (score 1):

Read the spec. Implicit grant is not for resource servers, and it specifically requires the token to be returned in the fragment of the URL (for good reasons). Your client either needs to be able to read the token from the fragment, or you need a different grant type (probably the latter).